# Unable to deploy website because of netlify showing 'could not resolve (path of img or svg file)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a problem in netlify and vercel to deploy a portfolio website and I wanted to show the skills as a svg icon. I imported the icons from the folder and it ran without any problems in developing but when I tried to deploy in netlify and it shows like this:

[image: Image of my error ("Could not resolve...")]

Here is the code that has the error: `import gcp from "../assets/svg/static/gcp.svg";`.

It showed the same problem for images but it stopped after I renamed the folder into static. It doesn't work in this issue though.

Comment: This maybe due to the build process. Have you tried renaming the `assets` folder to `public`, and then just using paths like `./svg/gcp.svg` in your markup/code? What are you using for the build? Vite or something else?

Comment: Thanks bro I just moved everything that caused file path error to public folder and it deployed without any issue. I was using Vite for build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just moved all the image and svg files to public folder and it worked without error. Thanks to Andy who helped me.